# Horizontallist variable width

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, width, horizontallist

i want to populate a horizontalList component from a xml file, the width value will be inside the xml file as well with all the data.

actually i have this code:

```
<mx:Model id="epg" source="epg.xml" /> 

<mx:Component id="customRend">
    <mx:Label text="{data.description}" width="{data.width}"/> 
</mx:Component>

<mx:HBox x="82" y="104" width="1203" height="113" verticalAlign="middle">
    <mx:HorizontalList width="100%"  dataProvider="{epg.channel.program}" 
        itemRenderer="{customRend}" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
    </mx:HorizontalList> 
</mx:HBox>
```

but it sets same width for all elements in the list.

Do you know how to do this?

Thanks a lot.
Br

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this:

- Set `label.width = data.width` on `creationComplete`
- Wrap Label in Canvas

The creationComplete way (probably because an itemRenderer should be a Container?):

```
<mx:HorizontalList width="100%" dataProvider="{epg.channel.program}"  horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component id="customRend">
            <mx:Label text="{data.description}" creationComplete="this.width = data.width"/> 
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:HorizontalList>
```

... or wrapped in Canvas:

```
<mx:HorizontalList width="100%" dataProvider="{epg.channel.program}"  horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component id="customRend">
            <mx:Canvas horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
                <mx:Label text="{data.description}" width="{data.width}"/> 
            </mx:Canvas>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:HorizontalList>
```

Hope that helps,
Lance

Comment: thanks for your help.

i tried this code, but still same issue. The width is always the same for all the elements, i have no hint about this :-(

Comment: i have flex builder 3, 
what i really want to implement is something like this http://jaganath.files.wordpress.com/2006/12/guide.PNG, maybe there is other easier component that i can use ...